# BLE characteristic changed callback executed only for first change after write

Tags: c#, bluetooth, notifications, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I try to subscribe to BLE characteristic notification using typical approach:

```
stCharacteristic = stService.GetCharacteristics(stCharacteristicGUID)[0];
await stCharacteristic.WriteClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorAsync(GattClientCharacteristicConfigurationDescriptorValue.Notify);
stCharacteristic.ValueChanged += stData_ValueChanged;
```

The callback function has also standard form:

```
async void stData_ValueChanged(GattCharacteristic sender, GattValueChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var values = (await sender.ReadValueAsync()).Value.ToArray();
}
```

The problem is that the callback is not always called when the BLE device changes characteristic's value. When I write something to the characteristic and the device writes something in reponse, then the callback is called. But if the devices writes to characteristic just by itself the callback is not called. The funny part is that the data are not lost. When I write something again, I get several calls to my callback with all the data sent by the BLE device in meantime. In other words it looks like Windows or .NET Framework caches subsequent incoming data until a write is made. After write only first characteristic change causes callback to be fired.

- incoming data - no callback
- sending data
- incoming data - two callbacks!
- sending data
- incoming data - one callback
- incoming data
- incoming data
- incoming data
- sending data - three callbacks!

Windows 10, VS2015

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to read the value in the ValueChanged callback. The value is already present in the GattValueChangedEventArgs.

Other than that - your handler should really be called directly and not after a write. Can you see if your device is disconnected / connected between the notifications?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I can get data from args and I'm sure it's more elegant.

The device is not disconnected. I can see it in device's logs. Moreover if there was disconnection I wouldn't be able to make writes to characteristic.

Meanwhile I observed interesting thing. The device can send packets of data larger than characteristic size (20 bytes). In this case it divides packets into 20-byte chunks. And I get all the chunks one by one without any problem. So the callback is executed not only for first chunk. It looks like there is time window after write when callback fires immediately.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was Windows 10 issue. And on Windows 10.0.15063 and newer, like 10.0.16251, it's even worse - there are no callbacks at all. Fortunately there is a simple workaround, two registry entries are needed to be added. Here is the .reg file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\{C6BFD646-3DF0-4DE5-B7AF-5FFFACB844A5}]
"AccessPermission"=hex:01,00,04,80,9c,00,00,00,ac,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,\
  00,00,02,00,88,00,06,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,07,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,\
  05,0a,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,03,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,12,00,00,00,\
  00,00,18,00,07,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00,00,\
  00,18,00,03,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,0f,02,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,\
  14,00,03,00,00,00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,13,00,00,00,00,00,14,00,03,00,00,\
  00,01,01,00,00,00,00,00,05,14,00,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,\
  20,02,00,00,01,02,00,00,00,00,00,05,20,00,00,00,20,02,00,00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\AppID\YOURAPP.exe]
"AppID"="{C6BFD646-3DF0-4DE5-B7AF-5FFFACB844A5}"
```

Change YOURAPP.exe to you exe file name. The GUID can be changed or left as it is. After applying this .reg file callbacks are called instantly every time and notifications are being received very well.

At the moment of writing this answer Microsoft was working on a permanent fix. The workaround and the discussion is here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58da3fdb-a0e1-4161-8af3-778b6839f4e1/bluetooth-bluetoothledevicefromidasync-does-not-complete-on-10015063?forum=wdk